# Delete text in input with backspace in ie11 make navigate to previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one issue with some rows and their information 
[image: here we have name and date created]

I can edit row name by move cursor on it and click on pencil that appears when mouseover
[image]

When i click pencil, it took focus on input with name and select all text

So, after this, i can delete all text in input with Backspace, but in IE11 (i dont know maybe in other IE same behavior) Backspace take me back to previous page in browser, when i try to do this. I use this part of code    `e.target.previousElementSibling.select();` for focus and select text, but it works, only when i click input by myself, backspace works right and delete sybmols in input, in other way - i go to prev page. Help me out, please
P.S: Ask in comments if you have some questions or dont understand something

Comment: can you create an example link (with hard-code value) so that we can check the problem

Comment: there is one trouble, it works fine if i create simple example https://jsfiddle.net/89dva2Lm/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i found a problem, the project using Angular 2, and problem was in bad way using readonly directive